# What happens when I applied for an UK visa (T5 - YMS) too far in advance?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

Hi I submitted a UK visa application 12 November with intended travel date 12 March.

This is 4 months & I have now heard they can only be forward dated by 3.

What is the probability of the issuing authority:

1. Reject the application - request I apply later
2. Date from application date (12 November) or date they approve it (December)
3. Date it 3 months from application date (Feb)

I then think if approved I will have to apply for the vignette transfer.

Comment: sorry I don't think I understand premise? my intention? to work

Comment: apologies, did not understand you meant type of visa - T5 youth mobility

Comment: We don't take bets on probabilities, but for a YMS I could see them taking a modified option 3 (forward dating from the decision date). At this point it's better to wait until you get your passport back and see if your application was successful and then ask a very SPECIFIC question about the best way to proceed.

Comment: What happened in the end_